# Duality $(M/N)^*\equiv N^\perp/M^\perp$ for closed subspaces $N\subset M$ of a Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a Banach space $X$. Then we can identify $(X/M)^*$ with $M^\perp$ and $M^*$ with $X^*/M^\perp$.

Indeed, if $Q^*:X\to X/M$ is the quotient map, then $Q^*:M^*\to X^*$ is a linear isometry with range $M^\perp$. Moreover, if $J:M\to X$ is the embedding, then $J^*:X^*\to M^*$ has kernel $M^\perp$ and induces a surjective linear isometry $\widehat{J^*}:X^*/M^\perp\to M^*$.

Let $M$ and $N$ be closed subspaces of a Banach space $X$ with $N\subset M$.
Then we can identify $(M/N)^*$ and $N^\perp/M^\perp$, I think.

Which operator induces the identification a similar way as in the above cases $N=\{0\}$ and $M=X$?

**Added June 17:** Is there a reference for this identification?

[cross-posted to m.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173533/duality-m-n-equiv-n-perp-m-perp-for-closed-subspaces-n-subset-m-of-a-b)

Comment: I know little functional analysis, but how are you defining $M^\perp$ for a *Banach* space? Don't you need a scalar product for that to make sense?

Comment: @DenisNardin I'd guess $M^\perp$ is the annihilator of $M$ in this case.

Comment: This does not belong to MO.

Comment: No answers in Mathematics.

Comment: This question has only been on MSE for 4 days... give people some time. I suggest that if no one answers in a week or two, then re-post here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been posted 4 days ago on MSE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is so often the case, the isomorphism is the only reasonable map you can write down in the general case:

$N^\perp / M^\perp \to (M/N)^\ast, f+M^\perp \mapsto (m+N \mapsto f(m))$

All that's left to prove is that it actually works ;-)